# Finding unique values from an input array based on their transformed values

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have been trying to figure out a solution for this question for the past couple of hours but i dont even understand the question to begin with.

The question is: "should return all unique values from the input array based on their transformed values if an iterator is provided as input"

the test code is

```
        // Note: The isSorted input parameter has absolutely no impact on functionality of this test.
        //       The isSorted input parameter can be safely ignored in your solution!

        var numbers = [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4];
        var otherNumbers = [11.2, 11.9, 12.4, 12.6];

        var isOne = function(value) { return value === 1; };
        var roundNumber = function(number) { return Math.round(number); };

        expect(_.uniq(numbers, false, isOne)).to.eql([1, 2]);
        expect(_.uniq(otherNumbers, true, roundNumber)).to.eql([11.2, 11.9, 12.6]);
      });
```

My code:

````
``` _.uniq = function(array, isSorted, iterator) {

      var transformed = [];
      
      for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (iterator(array[j])) {
          transformed.push(array[j]);
        }
      }
      return transformed;
  };
````

When i return transformed i get [1, 1, 1] as an answer when i should be getting [1, 2]. Any ideas why?

Comment: I am with you in that I don't understand the expectation.  The way I read the text, I would think this expectation should be: `expect(_.uniq(numbers, false, isOne)).to.eql([2,3,4]);` Because [2,3,4] is the list of uniques that evaluate to false when isOne is applied.

Comment: You should be looking for unique values of `iterator(array[j])`. Instead, you're just checking to see if `iterator(array[j])` is true. You'll need to modify your condition to instead see if it's a new, unique value rather than just truthy.

Comment: @DemiPixel Do you agree that that expectation seems off?

Comment: @ruby_newbie Not really, it's just misleading that the first one returns a boolean. You can see the next one returns a rounded number. The first input that returns true is 1. The first input that returns false is 2. Since everything else isn't unique (only true or false), it would return `[1, 2]`

Comment: @DemiPixel So would i just do: transformed.push(iterator(array[j]))? instead of the if statement? When i do that now my transformed array is [ true, false, true, false, true, false ]?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to determine whether the value returned from the iteratee is unique. Secondly, you have to return only the values for which this is the case. Thirdly, you have to return the values *from the original collection* for which this is the case, not the values that you obtain after transforming. Let's go through this for both examples.

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4];
var isOne = function(value) { return value === 1; };
expect(_.uniq(numbers, false, isOne)).to.eql([1, 2]);
```

The values returned by `isOne`, corresponding to `numbers`, are `[true, false, true, false, true, false]`. The *unique* values among these are `true` and `false`. The *original values corresponding to the first instances of those unique values* are `1` and `2`, respectively. This is why you need to return `[1, 2]`.

```
var otherNumbers = [11.2, 11.9, 12.4, 12.6];
var roundNumber = function(number) { return Math.round(number); };
expect(_.uniq(otherNumbers, true, roundNumber)).to.eql([11.2, 11.9, 12.6]);
```

The values returned by `roundNumber`, corresponding to `otherNumbers`, are `[11, 12, 12, 13]`. The *unique* values among those are `11`, `12` and `13`. The *original values corresponding to the first instances of those unique values* are `11.2`, `11.9` and `12.6`, respectively. This is why you need to return `[11.2, 11.9, 12.6]`.